# Boot to GRUB in new Ubuntu Install

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, uefi

I have a new single boot PC. I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS from a USB (this is not a dual boot machine). I encountered issues and so have reinstalled several times and still cannot get to boot into Ubuntu.

My BIOS lists the following boot options and this is what happens when I try them each separately:

- "ubuntu" - takes me to a screen with a grub> prompt
- "UEFI OS" - takes me to a screen with a grub> prompt
- "ubuntu (P4: Samsung SSD 870 EVO 1TB)" - takes me to a screen which says "Invalid signature detected. Check Secure Boot Policy in Setup"
- "UEFI OS (P4: Samsung SSD 870 EVO 1TB)" - takes me to a screen with a grub> prompt
- "UEFI: Samsung SSD 870 EVO 1TB" - takes me to a screen with a grub> prompt
- "ubuntu (P4: Samsung SSD 870 EVO 1TB)" - identical to the third option above but this one takes me to a grub> prompt

Disk layout

[image]

I have clearly royally shafted my hard-disk and yes you guessed it I really do not know what I am doing. I don't care about anything on the disk, it is empty anyway so happy with any "nuclear" suggestions. Just want to get Ubuntu up and running.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware & SSD firmware? (May not be related to specific issue.) Did you install in UEFI boot mode every time? Its as if your are booting one grub (like BIOS) but install is now UEFI or vice-versa. And invalid signature often related to UEFI Secure Boot, it that off? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred thanks so much for offering to help. I may well have tried to update the firmware, if by that you mean the option that the Ubuntu install offers to install 3rd Party Software. It asked me for a password that I would need to use later. However I never used it later on reboot, I think I must have missed the point in the reboot that offered me the opportunity to complete that operations - was it where I got a DOS style menu screen asking me for a MOK? Here is my pastebin link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GYmZxP8PNB/

Comment: @oldfred also don't know if it helps, but here is a screenshot of my disks taken whilst in the Live Ubuntu session booted from my USB. ![Drives](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z8BoZ74LZFGwLg-WB5Ae22gLMB0Df9V6/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Welcome, in the installation process do you select "Erase disk and install Ubuntu"? There are apparently 2 EFI partitions, there should be just 1. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity yeah I was sure I chose erase disk. *Ubuntu version is 20.04.3 LTS*.

Comment: You have very mixed installs. You have grub in MBR for BIOS boot & in ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot. Only one grub will be the last install and one that works. Any request for MOK key is related to proprietary driver & use of Secure Boot. Often easier to turn Secure Boot off. Ubuntu cannot verify that a proprietary driver blob is "Secure" but a user can with MOK key. You also have MBR partitioning & really with UEFI should use gpt partitioning. Turn off Secure boot, & erase MBR partitioning. If new install, no backup should be required, but backup data in other partition(s).

Comment: @oldfred thanks this sounds like exactly like the straightforward instructions I need. So what I will do based on your comment above and the one below is:  

1. Boot my system from my Ubuntu USB  
2. Install `gparted`  
3. Use `gparted` to select my one device and use the command `Create Partition Table`.  
4. Ensure that this will use the partition type of  `gpt`.  
  
  
As I understand it that will wipe all existing partitions and partition information and leave me with a pristine system on to which I can start installing Ubuntu ll over again.

Comment: oldfred, hermann and schrodigerscatcuriosity thank you all for your help. I used `gparted` to create a new partition table and started the install again and all seems to be working now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

I used `gparted` to create a new parition table, reinstalled Ubuntu and all seems well now. Thank @oldfred, @hermann and @schrodigerscatcuriosity.

Answer (score 0):

As you are seeing a `grub` prompt and not `grub rescue`, I assume GRUB itself is fine, but cannot access the configuration. You should be able to use the grub shell to gain some information.

Typing `ls`  and hitting tab, grub should give you a list of storage devices `(hd0) (hd1)`. If no storage devices are shown, then the UEFI firmware does something weird and is incompatible with grub.

You can also load modules providing additional features into grub, e.g. by entering `insmod part_gpt`. Now tab completion on `ls`  should also provide information about GPT partitions `(hd0,gpt1) (hd0,gpt2)` and their file-systems.

After loading `insmod ext2`, you should be able to access your root partition. `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` should exist on one of the file-systems. Tab completion will help you look for it. You can load it via `configfile (hdx,gpty)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Then grub should switch to menu mode and give you access to the Ubuntu installation.

Comment: typing `ls ` and hitting tab just gives me a list of commands. Typing `ls` and hitting enter gives me `(porc) (hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)`. After installing `part_gpt` and `ext2` `ls (hd0,msdos5)/` gives `lost+found/ boot/ swapfile etc/ media/ var/ bin dev/ home/ lib lib32 lib64 limx32 mnt/ opt/ proc/ root/ run/ sbin snap/ srv/ sys/ tmp/ usr/ cdrom/`.

Comment: `configfile (hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` briefly gave me an error about a missing font file and then rebooted into a graphical login screen. So wow and thank you. But restarting  takes me back to the `grub>` prompt. Is there a way to fix this permanently @Herman?

Comment: Since the partitions are listed as msdos I assume your drive is partitioned with MBR (for legacy BIOS / CSM boot), not with GPT (needed for UEFI boot). Yet your UEFI seems to load GRUB just fine. I am surprised this even works. Do you have more than one drive in your system?

Comment: No just one drive. I have to say that as part of trying to get this system to work (prior to coming to this forum and therefore really just flailing around in the dark) in between reinstall I messed around with "BIOS" UEFI settings so could have triggered all sorts of weird behaviour in the Ubuntu installer. Is there anyway I can just go back to a blank slate and start again?

Comment: @fponknevets you can use `efibootmgr` from a live usb to handle the UEFI entries in the BIOS.

Comment: If you use gparted from your live installer in live mode and say to convert from MBR to gpt it will totally erase drive. Then only boot installer in UEFI mode for UEFI install with gpt partitioning. For those who want to convert but keep some data you can use gdisk, but backups really required and total reinstall of grub required. Often better to use convert for data only drives and erase & do new install on system drives.